# how to limit eclipse compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to write an essay in computer science using java 1.6 only.
the problem that I have 1.8 installed in my computer.
is there a plugin for eclipse that show me warnings for 1.7 and 1.8 features?
thank you!

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to update their CS course, Java 6 has been end of life for quite some time now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin. You can set the Compliance level of the Eclipse Java compiler in the Preferences in 'Java > Compiler' (which sets the default for the whole workspace). You can also set the level in the Properties for a Project ('Java Compiler') properties.

Setting the compliance level to 1.6 will give you errors for 1.7 and 1.8 language features. However it will not warn you if you use classes and methods from the Java API which are not in 1.6 - only installing a 1.6 JDK can do that.

You can also tell Eclipse about multiple Java JRE/JDK installs in the Preferences in 'Java > Installed JREs' and then choose which one to use in each project.